# Angular Routing is not working. Crud Button and Pipe Button on Tool Bar are both displaying the table of my home page?

Tags: angular, angular-material, crud, angular-routing, angular-pipe

Following is my code:

- [Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvqHz.jpg)
- [CRUD Button, on my toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APZaj.jpg)
- [PIPES Button, on my toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB0d2.jpg)

- I'm working on a Reactive Form with JSON Server + WEB API for CRUD Operation. I've created two buttons on my Toolbar namely CRUD and PIPE and also their components. When I click on either button, the default line "crud works" or "pipe works" written in each components html is displayed just below my home page's table. I've also inserted an image for both kindly check those to understand the query better. I've rechecked my router links and paths but I'm unable to figure out the issue.
- When I click on CRUD Button it should display the same data and table as well as format of the page as I have on my home i.e. the main page.

**APP COMPONENT HTML**

```
   <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z6">
   <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu 
    icon">
     <mat-icon>group_work</mat-icon>
    </button>

  <span> ANGULAR </span>

  <!-- LINKS FOR : CRUD & PIPE -->
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <a mat-button routerLink="crud"  routerLinkActive="active"> CRUD </a>
  <a mat-button routerLink="pipes" routerLinkActive="active"> PIPES </a>
   </mat-toolbar>


   <!-- EMPLOYEE FORM TABLE TEMPLATE -->
   <div class="container">
   <div style="margin-top: 70px;">

   <!-- ADD EMPLOYEE BUTTON -->
   <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="openDialog()"><mat-icon>add</mat- 
   icon>ADD EMPLOYEE</button>

   <!-- pasting the template below -->
   <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <!-- First Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> FIRST NAME </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstname}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Last Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> LAST NAME </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lastname}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Email Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> EMAIL </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.email}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> POSITION </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Action Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ACTION </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 

     <!-- edit employee icon btn -->
      <button mat-icon-button  (click)="editEmployee(row)" color="primary">
        <mat-icon> edit </mat-icon>
      </button>  
     
      <!-- delete employee icon btn -->
      <button (click)="deleteEmployee(row.id)" mat-icon-button color="warn">
        <mat-icon> delete </mat-icon>
      </button> 
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**APP ROUTING MODULE**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CrudComponent } from './crud/crud.component';
import { PipesComponent } from './pipes/pipes.component';

const routes: Routes = [
// {path:'',  component: AppComponent},
{path:'crud',  component: CrudComponent},
{path:'pipes', component: PipesComponent}];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
// export const routingComponents =[CrudComponent,PipesComponent]
```

**APP MODULE TS**

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
 import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
 import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
 import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
 import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
 import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';
 import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
 import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
 import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
 import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import {MatTableDataSource, MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
 import { PipesComponent } from './pipes/pipes.component';
 import { CrudComponent } from './crud/crud.component';
 import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 DialogComponent,
 PipesComponent,
 CrudComponent

 ],
 imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatToolbarModule,
MatIconModule,
MatButtonModule,
MatDialogModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule,
MatSelectModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,

MatTableModule,
MatSortModule,

  // RouterModule.forRoot([
  //   {path: 'crud', component: CrudComponent},
  //   {path: 'pipes', component: PipesComponent}
  // ]),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] })
  export class AppModule { }
```

**CRUD COMPONENT HTML**

```
<p>crud works!</p>
```

**PIPES COMPONENT HTML**

```
<p>pipes works!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported the wrong modules in your typescript file.